# How to listen to key press repetitively in Dart for games?

Tags: keyboard, dart, keypress

I know that you can listen to key press and down events with Dart like:

```
var el = query('#el');
el.on.keyDown.add((e) {});
```

But the problem here is that it fires only **once**. I want repetition.

So, I tried `keyPress` instead, but it has a slight delay before the repetition. I am working on a game and I want it to fire instantly and repetitively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, don't listen to `keyPress` events, because the "initial delay" depends on the operating system configuration! In fact, `keyPress` events may not even fire repetitively.

What you need to do is to listen to `keyDown` and `keyUp` events. You can make a helper for this.

```dart
class Keyboard {
  HashMap<int, int> _keys = new HashMap<int, int>();

  Keyboard() {
    window.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      // If the key is not set yet, set it with a timestamp.
      if (!_keys.containsKey(e.keyCode))
        _keys[e.keyCode] = e.timeStamp;
    });

    window.onKeyUp.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      _keys.remove(e.keyCode);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Check if the given key code is pressed. You should use the [KeyCode] class.
   */
  isPressed(int keyCode) => _keys.containsKey(keyCode);
}
```

Then depending on what you do in your game, you probably have "a game loop" of some sort, in your `update()` method that gets called in every once in a while:

```dart
class Game {
  Keyboard keyboard;

  Game() {
    keyboard = new Keyboard();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

  update(e) {
    if (keyboard.isPressed(KeyCode.A))
      print('A is pressed!');

    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
}
```

Now your game loop checks repetitively for `A` key pressing.

Comment: You may want to clear out all the keyboard presses after the game loop. See also https://github.com/sethladd/bad-aliens-dart which I realize now I probably need to update :)

Comment: I've written an article on keyboard handling for games in Dart: http://dartgamedevs.org/blog/2012/12/11/keyboard-input/

Comment: @Cutch the link is dead. Probably this: https://github.com/dartgamedevs/dartgamedevs.org/blob/master/source/_posts/2012-12-11-keyboard-input.markdown

Comment: I used the code in a keyboard class in a turn based - very simple - game. It didn't work when I switched focus to another window or application. I added an extra listener to make it work: window.onFocus.listen((onData){
      _keys.clear();
    });