# Imposible to use core-a11y-keys with Inputs

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

Dart, Polymer 0.5, Dartium.

In a page I have some `div` element with `core-a11y-keys` inside, keys are "up down left right". It works perfectly, some actions are happened after key down.

Also I have input field on the page. And problem is I can't use arrow keys in it because of `core-a11y-keys`.

Question is: how to avoid destruction behavior?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="widgetContainer">
        <core-a11y-keys target="{{body}}" keys="up down left right"
                        on-keys-pressed="{{widgetContainer_on_move_keys}}">
        </core-a11y-keys>
    </div>
    <input id="txtInput">
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please provide some code that allows to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `target` attribute of `core-a11y-keys` is in fact present and targeting the `div`, otherwise it will apply to the whole page including your `input`. See here for more detail on how to do that: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/web/k8Wzj6KCfgM

If your `input` was a child of the `div` that your `core-a11y-keys` was targeting, it would be doing what you instructed it to do anywhere in that `div`: intercepting keystrokes. In that case, you would need to handle the `onKeyPress` event in the `input` like `<input on-keypress="{{handleInputKeyStrokes}}">`:

```
handleInputKeyStrokes(Event e) {
  // You'll need one or both of these; not sure which.
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I haven't tried this, and it may be that you need `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` instead, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746419.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, input is not in div with `core-a11y-keys`. I don't need capture events on `input`, I just need input to work well. In my case impossible to use arrow keys in it, just doesn't work.

Comment: This solution doesn't works for my problem. I can't catch events on my target div because there is no any element with focusable interface. I can catch events on body only.

Comment: Your code in your question does not show a `target` attribute. See my answer again, the first sentence. Have you included a target?

Comment: Yes, you're right about `target` property. I have played with target and can split events from different targets.

But this means nothing for me because of my `div` doesn't contain any focusable element. I can point this div as target but I never get any event. My problem is I must catch events on a body level and in this case it brokes input placed somewhere in a body tag (of course!). It doesn't matter where is core-a11y-keys.